# Using xcodebuild and a Today Extension I get a PBXCp error

Tags: ios, xcode, screenshot, xcodebuild

I'm using [UI-Screen-Shooter](https://github.com/jonathanpenn/ui-screen-shooter) to compile my app for screenshots. After I added a Today Extension the compilation won't finish due to not finding the AppExtension.appex directory. The directory is there but under a different name than xcodebuild is expecting. It is called app.appex and Xcode is looking for PhotoMind Upcoming.appex.

It fails with this PBXCp error:

/tmp/screen_shooter/PhotoMind Upcoming.appex: No such file or directory

How would tell xcodebuild that it is called app.appex instead of the name it is looking for?

Answer (score 4):

I didn't find how to change the path of the Extension in Xcode build, but I was able to get [UI-Screen-Shooter](https://github.com/jonathanpenn/ui-screen-shooter) to build and run my app by checking the Copy only when installing box in the Build Phases settings.

[image: Build Setting]

Answer (score 0):

1. Select "Extension" Target ----> Build Settings;
2. Search "name" or "Product Name",
3. Setting the "Product Name" (of "Extension" Target) to "app".